# Custom style on popup from reactjs-popup

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, popup

I want to add custom styles to the popups from [reactjs-popup](https://react-popup.elazizi.com/).

I tried adding a style argument to the  tag, no change. I tried editing the css classes added to the popup by the package, still no change. I have not yet tried delving into the code to find out how this would work, that'll be my last resort if nothing here helps.

Their npmjs page claims to have "Full style customization", but the documentation doesn't include how to utilize it. I would expect there to be some way to change every aspect, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `contentStyle` attribute in Popup. E.g.)

```
<Popup contentStyle={{width: "300px"}} trigger=...></Popup>
```

Answer (score 1):

Custom Popup ClassName will be merged with the component element:
`className='foo'` means `foo-arrow` to style arrow, `foo-overlay` to style `overlay` and `foo-content` to style popup `content`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was reading the documentation tutorials, rather than the api. Silly me.
Here is a link to the actual api for anyone as blind as me:
https://react-popup.elazizi.com/component-api